# How to add # in front of multiple line of code?

Tags: textwrangler

I see others do this but have no clue how they did.
As title, if I want to add # in front of multiple line of code so that these code wont run, like this

```
print A
print B
print C
```

Then I want them become

```
# print A
# print B
# print C
```

What is the fastest way?

Comment: Check out the documentation of your code editor.

Comment: This is a question about your editor, not the python language.

Comment: For PyCharm it is `Ctrl+Slash`

Comment: You should ask these "others" how they do it

Answer (score 1):

In python multiline comments can be used as follows:

```
'''print A
print B
print C'''
```

There are no multi line comments in python, just make the code as multi line string to ignore its execution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for mentioning that this is a problem of text editor not the python program itself.

And this movement is call "Comment/Uncomment" a block of code.

I am using textwrangler, so it is "command (or ⌘ for mac)" + "/".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your editor. For example, with IDLE you can quickly comment out multiple lines by highlighting them and pressing Alt+3 and uncomment them with Alt+4, but I cannot say that it's the same for you.